# XMPP Anonymous session JID RID SID with Matrix XMPP SDK

Tags: matrix, xmpp

Please help me to retrieve XMPP Anonymous session JID, RID and SID using Matrix XMPP SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post should answer your question:
http://www.ag-software.de/2012/01/31/bosh-prebind-in-matrix-and-attach-to-strophe/

Comment: yes i saw this post but the problem is that Prebind method with login credentials called instead of Open which i use for anonymous login. And i can't get to OnPrebind event just replacing Open with Prebind

Comment: Prebind can work also with Anonymous login. Do you want to Prebind and attach? If not why do you need the Rid and Sid?

Comment: yes i want to attach after prebind. Could you please provide me a code example of how to prebind with anonymous login (Matrix SDK .NET)?

Comment: see here how to manual select the SASL mechanism for authentication:
http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/matrix-developer-tutorial/#authentication-manual-sasl-selection